# WHERE clause in LEFT JOIN query

Tags: mysql, null, left-join, isnull

So i wish to get all the the SSC positions and get the number of positions which are not yet occupied. However, i somehow got stuck in the where clause.

Here is my table structures:

[image: Position]

[image: SSC]

[image: Student]

[image: Account]

And here is my query

`SELECT p.position_id, a.account_id 
            FROM positions p 
            LEFT JOIN ssc s ON s.position_id = p.position_id AND s.removed = 0
            LEFT JOIN students stud ON stud.students_id = s.students_id
            LEFT JOIN accounts a ON a.account_id = stud.account_id
            WHERE p.user_level_id = 6 
            AND p.removed = 0`

The actual result is this:

[image: Result]

Expected result to show only the fields which are NULL in account_id. However if I include `AND a.account_id = NULL` in the query, the result is empty. And if i ever change the query into:

`SELECT p.position_id, a.account_id 
            FROM positions p 
            LEFT JOIN ssc s ON s.position_id = p.position_id AND s.removed = 0
            LEFT JOIN students stud ON stud.students_id = s.students_id
            LEFT JOIN accounts a ON a.account_id = stud.account_id AND a.account_id = NULL
            WHERE p.user_level_id = 6 
            AND p.removed = 0`

Then all the account ID becomes NULL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of them `=` the `NULL` value. Use `IS NULL`.

```
a.account_id IS NULL
```

You can read more about this here, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html. You may prefer to use empty strings, or a default value of `0`.